# Visual Web Developer Express Javascript Breakpoints not hit

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints, visual-web-developer

I'm using Visual Web Developer Express 2012 for Web.

I'm facing an issue performing debugging. It says, "this breakpoint will not be hit, no symbols have been loaded for this document" while debugging.

I'm using IE to run my website project and currently using my IE debugger. This is too much of a task and debugging is very difficult this way, because,  everytime I close the browser, I lose all the breakpoints set and have to do it again.

I want to debug using the IDE and not the browser debugger.

Comment: IE verison used is IE 9

Answer (score 0):

In IE9 (only one instance): Tools > Internet Options > Advanced tab > In Browsing category > Clear "Disable script debugging" check boxes (both) > restart IE.

In VS 2012: Run the Page Inspector ( when javascript error box opens, click No ! )

Choose from VS menu: DEBUG > Attach to process...
Select your IE instance and click Attach.

Debugging works pretty well, but it's one condition. Don't insert any breakpoints in your code (or clear them before - DEBUG > Delete All Breakpoints). There can cause a lot of problems - from hanging and frozing to entirely crashing your VS.

You can also get some help here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7seh8d72.aspx

Hope this helps.

Comment: under DEBUG menu, i dont find the Attach to process.. option

Comment: Unfortunately attach To Process is not available in the Express Editions. You will need to purchase a full version to get this done. Try to close all IE instances Attach To Process is not available in the Expressor the Web Developer Editions. You will need to purchase a full version.

Comment: Then how do i debug ? Please help. Are you saying it is not possible to debug in express edition ? .. It definitely is possible. Other people at my workplace are able to debug in express edition. I`m not sure what is the issue with my copy of web developer express..

Answer (score 0):

I happened to fix this issue of breakpoints not getting hit by doing a clean installation of VSW express 2012. It works well after that.